# Ending threads when system goes to sleep/suspend C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I have threads doing some work. While the work is in progress and if a user makes the system to sleep/suspend, I want the threads to end there itself. The problem I am facing right now is that when I resume from sleep the threads have not ended and my application hangs. Do I have to make eventhandler to handle this and if yes how?

My threads are created in UI(C#). The sleep/suspend is handled in C++ code.

Comment: Don't you want the threads to pick up work where they ended?

Comment: I would focus my effort on understanding why the threads crash rather than smoothly resume.

Comment: Post the code please. Sleeping or suspending a thread won't end it, it just won't be executed on the CPU. It sounds like you've suspended a UI or a thread doing something that blocks. Are you trying to resume them when the computer exits sleep mode?

Comment: Ending your threads would end up with a race condition. Sometimes the computer might go to sleep before your thread ends and sometimes the thread might end first.

Comment: @huadinz: I do not want the threads to pick up the work on resume. I just want them to abort as soon as the user goes to sleep/suspend. I want the task that is currently running to end as soon as the user goes to sleep. The task is run by the 2 threads, one which does the work and the other for checking errors. wndproc catches the sleep/suspend. wndproc has been overridden in c++. As soon as it catches the sleep/suspend I want the 2 threads in UI to end the task.

Comment: @Eric: The threads do not crash. they simply do not end. I just want them to abort from c++ code.

Comment: @o______o: I am not trying to resume the process. The ideal situation is that the UI and the task should shutdown when the user resumes from sleep.

Comment: @MikeKulls: Yeah, I want the thread to end as soon as user goes to sleep so that when he resumes the code for UI exit takes place and the UI shuts down along with the task.

Comment: Sleep just saves the state of the CPU, when it resumes after sleep your threads should restart as if they had never been stopped--there's not reason that would cause your application to hang.  You need to provide more detail to get at the root of the problem.  Alternatively, you could look at Eric's answer; but if you can't stop your threads in time you'll be in the same boat.  I think it's better to find out why you app is hanging in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Power Management Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to detect when the system is going to sleep and react.

To use them, you override WndProc and listen for WM_POWERBROADCAST events

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
        ...
    }
}
```

There's a very good overview with detailed example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192084/Responding-to-Windows-power-management-events-stan